# Unable to create Salesforce PushTopic wih query on Event object

Tags: sobject, event, pushtopic

I'm trying to create a `PushTopic` on `Event` object using REST API with data

```
{
    "Name" : "EventTopic",
    "Query" : "SELECT Id,Subject,Location,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,IsDeleted,IsAllDayEvent FROM Event",
    "ApiVersion" : 41.0,
    "NotifyForOperationCreate" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationUpdate" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationUndelete" : true,
    "NotifyForOperationDelete" : true,
    "NotifyForFields" : "Referenced"
}
```

But the response says, its not supported, with `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

```
[ {
  "message" : "'Event' is not supported",
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_FIELD",
  "fields" : [ "Query" ]
} ]
```

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `Event` object is not supported by Streaming API.

Based on the context you can do following-

1. For Visualforce, You can use [`apex:actionPoller`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm).
2. Outside Salesforce:

   - Manage a shadow custom object via Apex trigger [Disadvantage: extra object and trigger].
   - <strike>Poll the records in some interval [Disadvantage: would not be real time].</strike>

You can vote the idea here- [`Support Event object in PushTopic queries`](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNc1QAE), after having enough votes maybe Salesforce will add it someday (remember Safe harbour statement).

---

Quoting From trailhead module - [Use Streaming API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_streaming):

> **Supported Objects in PushTopic Queries**
>
> PushTopic queries support all custom objects. PushTopic queries
>   support the following standard objects.
>
> - Account
> - Campaign
> - Case
> - Contact
> - Lead
> - Opportunity
> - Task

Comment: How can I poll for the Events, looks like there's no list Url for events, So I can't get the IDs. CAn you point me to a resource using polling for events?

Comment: Sorry that option was wrong, I didn't think enough. only option would be having a shadow object.